# Gitlab CloudFormation Integration Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

**Description:** Attempting to create a simple pipeline to create a cloudformation stack in an aws account.
Looks like its failing to find a script referenced in the documentation below, but I thought cloudformation cli commands were now supported in gitlab 13.9?

Gitlab Version:13.9

CI/CD variables setup:
See required ones here.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/

gitlab yaml file
variables:
REGION: us-east-2
CI_AWS_CF_STACK_NAME: 'gitlabTestStack'
CI_AWS_CF_CREATE_STACK_FILE: 'aws/aws-test-stack.yaml'

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest  
  script:
    - gl-cloudprovision create-stack
```

**Output**

```
    on PDOCK009-Runner-TestAutomation6 UrKKxyCW
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest ...
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:a39347bds862894f38dabf38f1fddfa0avbc1dc3070ca12400fd0a8d33e7178 for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest ...
Preparing environment
Running on runner-urkkxycw-project-1427-concurrent-0 via 9cdf65ce059d...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/jackoneill/aws-deploy/.git/
Created fresh repository.
From <URL>
 * [new ref]         fbf7a9b966f0be1e2db8fbf7a983c02c90ed8saxc2323x -> refs/pipelines/65421
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Checking out fbf7a9 master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
Downloading artifacts
00:02
Running before_script and script
00:02
$ gl-cloudprovision create-stack
/usr/bin/bash: line 103: gl-cloudprovision: command not found
Running after_script
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to change image to

```
image: 'registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-cloudformation:latest'
```

and script from

```
- gl-cloudprovision create-stack
```

to

```
- gl-cloudformation create-stack
```

Comment: Will you add a link to documentation?